# Custom option in adding element of type

Tags: symfony

I have form and have two methods like this

```
/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Justart\InvoiceBundle\Entity\InvoiceElement',
        'validation_groups' => 'invoiceElementValidation',
        'translation_domain' => 'JustartInvoiceBundle',
        'invoice_revision' => false,
    ));
}

public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    if (!empty($options['invoice_revision'])) {
        $view->vars['invoice_revision'] = $options['invoice_revision'];
    }
}
```

form name is `InvoiceElementType`

and I have form named `InvoiceType` which has elements so I wrote:

```
$builder->add('invoice_elements', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type' => InvoiceElementType::class,
    'allow_add' => true,
    'by_reference' => false,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'label' => false,
    'entry_options'  => array(
        'label' => false,
    ),
    'required' => true,
    'constraints' => array(
        new NotBlank(array('groups' => array('STANDARD','PROFORM','FINISH','ADVANCE'))),
    ),
    'invoice_revision' => $this->isRevision,
))
```

when I run it i get error

> The option "invoice_revision" does not exist. Defined options are:
>   "action" ...

So what I do wrong?

And how can I send a variable from controller to type?  I tried :

```
$form = $this->createForm(new Form\InvoiceType(1), $invoice);
```

construct of InvoiceType require integer value but I get error that createForm except string in first parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `invoice_revision` option under `entry_options` key:

```
'entry_options'  => array(
    'label' => false,
    'invoice_revision' => $this->isRevision,
),
```